# What's the difference between ASP.NET Web Applications and Websites?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Currently, I am reading *Pro ASP.NET 4 in C#* and in it, two ways of creating a web application are described:

- Website
- Web Application Project

In which scenarios should I choose the former over the latter, and vice versa?

Comment: This question has been asked ad nauseum over on stackoverflow.com. Here's a link to a good one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application ... feel free to type `web site vs application` into the search sometime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft made a table listing the differences between the two models, and when to use one instead of the other, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5
This is exactly what you are looking for, and the explanations are very easy to understand.

In short: "web application projects" may be formed of multiple Visual Studio projects and are also to be used for websites designed around the MVC pattern. Whereas a "Web site" project is just that, one "web" project and all files must be contained inside (you may however link to other assemblies); it is better suited for old-school ASP.Net websites.

That article I linked to above gives a lot more information, check it out!

Comment: Websites aren't necesarily just one project.  We have multiple ASP.NET Websites that haven't been converted to Web Applications yet, and they all share some common assemblies.

Comment: I edited my answer, what I meant was that you have one "web" project but that does not mean it cannot depend on other project references, or other assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

There is a HUGE list of reasons to use one over the other, but usually when I'm making a decision I base it on a few parameters.  For instance, do you want your code files to be out in the open (well, still behind server security) or would you rather they are compiled into code libraries?

Answer (score -3):

In ASP.NET website, if we create any class files/functions those will be placed in ASP.NET folder and it's compiled into many DLLs at runtime.

In ASP.NET Web Application, If we create any class files/functions those will be placed anywhere in the applications folder structure and it is precomplied into one single DLL.

You need more help, go to http://www.keenesystems.com/Expertise/ASPNetWebApplications.aspx